# How can I check if a tar file can be written to using the tarfile module?

Tags: python, tar, tarfile

I'm looking to append to a .tar file using `tarfile` but I don't know if the file is in use or not. How can I check to see if the file can be appended to?

I've tried:

```
try:
   with tarfile.open("foo.tar", "a:") as tar:
      tar.add("bar.txt")
except tarfile.TarError:
   print "error"
```

and this will sometimes get the error but sometimes it doesn't and the tar file at the end doesn't have all the files I'd expect.

My plan is to have this in a loop and keep trying until it works.

I have other options most of which involve leaving the taring to another process but I feel that `tarfile` should be responsible for this sort of thing. I could write a wrapper for `tarfile` that checks the new file appears on the `tar.getmembers()` list.

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't be writing to any file if it is even *possible* that it is in use. While append-mode is safe for simple files like logs where no line is above the buffer size, tarfiles need to overwrite the last few blocks.

Comment: @o11c I'm not sure what you mean by the "tarfiles need to overwrite the last few blocks".

Comment: `.tar` files consist of a (non-seekable) sequence of 512-byte records. The end of an archive is marked by at least two consecutive zero-filled records. In order to append, you have to eliminate the zeroed records.

Answer (score 2):

The *only* safe way to do this is:

- Make a copy of the file.
- Open the *copy* in append mode.
- Rename the copy over the original.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't there a problem that 2 processes will make a copy at the same time, add to different copies then one of them will get re-named over the top of the other?

Comment: @R.Mckemey Yes, that's a possibility. If you control all the code you can use `flock`. But, even in the *worst* case, you atomically lose one of the updates (similar to power loss or crashing process), rather than getting a corrupted file.